# IE7 and Firefox relative path resolving mismatch

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

This is my code inside smarty tpl file(or for any simple HTML):

```
<img src="../images/blah.jpg" />
```

Now in Firefox the path is resolving to: localhost/app/index.php/images/blah.jpg(and of course image is not loading).And in IE7 its resolving correctly(localhost/app/images/blah.jpg).

Can any one please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try maybe `"/images/blah.jpg"`? I don't know exactly how the site is set up; it might not work correctly unless you have something like `<base href="http://localhost/app/" />` in the head tag

Comment: this is mistagged as php, there is nothing related to php here

Comment: @JoshToth I am not using base href.I can add it.But while deploying I guess I have to change it again from localhost to actual domain.right?

Comment: @jonathan actually the code is inside smarty tpl file.So I have added php tag also.As the main concern here is to remove index.php part elegantly.I will remove php tag if needed.

Comment: What's this? Firefox is ***wrong***?!? Well I never.

Comment: What does the URI of the page this is on look like?  If it ends in 'index.php/' then the Firefox behavior is in fact correct....

Comment: @grails_enthu Yeah, if you're not using it, *add* it and you'll have to update once you're live. The reason it happens is because when you're working locally, (are you using MAMP?) the localhost thinks that your root folder is where the site is hosted. The problem occurs when you have ROOT/root_of_this_site/images/. Base href is supported by all major browsers, and it's not too hard to change it once you're live :)

Comment: @JoshToth Thanks.Please post above comment as answer. I'll accept it.And yes I am using WAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using it, add it and you'll have to update once you're live. The reason it happens is because when you're working locally, (are you using MAMP?) the localhost thinks that your root folder is where the site is hosted. The problem occurs when you have ROOT/root_of_this_site/images/. Base href is supported by all major browsers, and it's not too hard to change it once you're live :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `images/` sits in the same folder as your `index.php`, you should be just fine with:

```
<img src="images/blah.jpg" />
```